# Amazon EC2: Can we use our own license for Suse Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, licensing, sles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We have an existing SUSE Linux server with license we want to move to Amazon EC2. I want to know if we can pay the [standard Linux prices](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) if using our own license, or if we have to pay the more expensive [SUSE price schedule](http://aws.amazon.com/suse/).

The server will be always on (running a website) so we will be using a reserved instance. However I don't want to buy a reserved Linux instance and then find that the SUSE ami doesn't work with that and will only run in a reserved SUSE instance. So does anyone know if the SUSE ami will run in a reserved Linux instance?

The ami we'd like to use is [ami-eea35787](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=4294&categoryID=331) (provided by SUSE).

Answer (score 1):

The [Amazon EC2 Running IBM](http://aws.amazon.com/ibm/) page, specifically the "Bring Your Own IBM Software and License (BYOSL)" section indicates that so long as you you have acquired software entitlements under IBM’s International Passport Advantage or Passport Advantage Express Agreements (collectively PA or PA Program), you should only have the pay the normal Amazon EC2 prices and nothing extra.

Comment: That page doesn't seem to mention anything about Novell/Suse/SLES licenses though, only the IBM licenses.

Comment: Doesn't IBM now own Novell/Suse? I will keep looking to see what else I can find for you though.